# R Simulation Programming

Tags: r, simulation

Gamblers Ruin. In this case a gambler starts with $6. Imagine the game is tossing a coin which has 1/2 probability of win/lose. Now every win gives you 1$ and every lose -1$. The code below will simulate this situation a times and it will stop if he reaches 0$ or a certain amount let's say for example 10$. But the problem is I don't know how to store a track of his stake for example in trial 1 will show 6 5 4 3 2 1 0. How do i do it?

```
gamble <- function(k,n,p) {                                             
   stake <- k                                   
   while (stake > 0 & stake < n) {
         bet <- sample(c(-1,1),1,prob=c(1-p,p))
         stake <- stake + bet }                                                     
    if (stake == 0) return(1) else return(stake)}  
         storage <- vector("list", 100)                                     
         k <- 6       
         n <-  10  
         p <- 1/2  
         trials <- 100
    simlist <- replicate(trials, gamble(k, n, p))              
    print(simlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified `gamble` so that instead of updating a single `stake` value each time, `stake` is a vector and we track our place in it with `i`. A *terrible* way to do this would be to append a new value to `stake` at each iteration - making vectors longer one item at a time is horribly inefficient. Instead, we initialize `stake` with a generous 10k `NA` values. If we run out, we stick another 10k on the end.

I've otherwise kept as much of your code as possible.

```
gamble <- function(k, n, p) {
  stake <- rep(NA_real_, 1e4)
  i <- 1
  stake[1] <- k
  while (stake[i] > 0 & stake[i] < n) {
    bet <- sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob = c(1 - p, p))
    stake[i + 1] <- stake[i] + bet
    i <- i + 1
    if (length(stake) == i) stake <- c(stake, rep(NA_real_, 1e4))
  }
  return(stake[!is.na(stake)])
}

k <- 6
n <-  10
p <- 1 / 2
trials <- 100
simlist <- replicate(trials, gamble(k, n, p))
head(simlist)
# [[1]]
# [1] 6 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1]  6  7  6  5  6  5  4  3  2  3  4  3  4  5  4  5  4  5  6  7  8  7  8  7  6  7  8  7
# [29]  8  9  8  7  6  7  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
# 
# [[4]]
#  [1] 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 6 5 4 5 6 7 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 3 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 1 0
# 
# [[5]]
#  [1] 6 5 6 5 4 3 4 3 2 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7 6 5 4 5 4 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 2 1 2 3
# [43] 2 3 2 3 2 1 0
# 
# [[6]]
#  [1]  6  7  6  7  8  7  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: .thank you for this Mr. I have a question: Can I put a limit in tracking my bet?  because i noticed there are some simulations which has so many stakes to track. Can i limit the simulations maximum at 20? so even if it will not end at 0 or 1 if it reaches 20 stakes it will stop.

Comment: Of course you can! `i` tracks the number of bets so far in each simulation, so I bet if you try to add a condition based on `i` to the `while` loop you can figure it out. You can also simplify my code if you know that the maximum possible number of bets is 20, you definitely don't need 10k+ iterations.

Comment: Let's say I've already figured it out and now I want to count simulations ending in 0 or 10. Is there a way to do it? I know how to tally the total for each list but in identifying only those list ending in a given specific number sounds mystery to me. by the way that you very much for your help Mr. I'm new in R that's why.

Comment: `sapply(simlist, tail, 1)` gets the last value from each list. I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified version of your `gamble` function: The empty `track` array initialized before the while loop will keep a track of the different values of the stake up to the point where it reaches the minimum or maximum value

```
gamble <- function(s, mi, ma, p){
  stake <- s
  track <- array()
  counter <- 1
  while(stake > mi & stake < ma) {
    bet <- sample(c(-1,1),1,prob=c(1-p,p))
    stake <- stake + bet
    track[counter] <- stake
    counter = counter + 1
    if (counter > 20) break
  }
  return(track)
}

p <- 0.5
starting_value <- 6
mi <- 0
ma <- 10
trials <- 10
#track <- gamble(starting_value, mi, ma, p)
simlist <- replicate(trials, gamble(starting_value, mi, ma, p)) 

end_sims <- vector()
counter <- 1
for (i in 1:trials) {
  if (simlist[[i]][length(simlist[[i]])] == 0 | simlist[[i]][length(simlist[[i]])] == 10) {
    end_sims[counter] <- i
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this @SmithM. I've got 2 answers which which are both modified differently. This one shows 1 simulation/run. And I'm just going to replicate this method. But for instances like 1 run shows more than 20 values is there a possible way I can limit it to 20 even if it doesn't end with 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes @RodelG.Aldema you can simply insert a break statement. Check my edit

Comment: is it possible count the number of simulations ending only ending in 10 or 0? Just learned some basics in R a month ago and now I'm trying to simulate problems hehe please forgive me for my curiosity.

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well. Check my edited answer

Comment: thanks. Trying to translate it what happened in the last part i noticed that simlist[[i]] will call each list. But in the latter I'm still confused how did it collect only values ending with 0 and 10. I'm trying to figure out length[[i]]==0, I thought length command is only to know how many values are there in a list. I'm quite impressed by how it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. simlist[[i]] will collect all the vectors one by one. and then to get the last element I have done length(simlist[[i]]) because it may be different for each trial

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. The first idea is to do many trials at once. So instead of the original implementation, we have

```
gamble0 <-
    function(n_trials, k, n, p)
{
    ## create n_trials simulations
    stakes <- rep(k, n_trials)
    trials <- seq_len(n_trials)

    repeat {
        ## bet on all trials still in play, and update
        bet <- sample(c(1, -1), length(trials), TRUE, prob=c(1-p, p))
        stakes[trials] <- stakes[trials] + bet

        ## only continue to follow those trials that have not terminated
        trials <- trials[(stakes[trials] > 0L) & (stakes[trials] < n)]
        if (length(trials) == 0)
            break
    }
    stakes
}
```

The result is a vector of outcomes, and is computed quickly because we allow R to do *vectorized* calculations (e.g., calling `sample()` once to generate `length(trials)` outcomes, rather than calling it `length(trials)` times).

```
> n <- 100000
> system.time(answer <- gamble0(n, 6, 10, .5))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.336   0.000   0.338 
> table(answer) / n
answer
      0      10 
0.39973 0.60027
```

To accumulate tracks in each simulation, use a `list()` to keep track of each track and trial still in play. Once we've recorded the outcome of all tracks, transform the list-of-iterations to a list-of-tracks by creating a single vector (via `unlist()`) of tracks and trials and using `split()` to re-split the vector based on tracks.

```
gamble2 <-
    function(n_trials, k, n, p)
{
    ## lists to hold tracks
    tracks <- trials <- list()
    ## initial conditions
    i <- 1L
    stakes <- rep(k, n_trials)
    trial <- seq_len(n_trials)
    repeat {
        ## store current tracks
        tracks[[i]] <- stakes
        trials[[i]] <- trial
        ## still more to do?
        idx <- (stakes > 0L) & (stakes < n)
        if (!any(idx))
            break
        ## update tracks that are still in play
        bet <- sample(c(1, -1), sum(idx), TRUE, c(1 - p, p))
        stakes <- tracks[[i]][idx] + bet
        trial <- trials[[i]][idx]
        ## increment step
        i <- i + 1L
    }
    ## reshape results from list-of-iterations to list-of-tracks
    tracks <- unlist(tracks, use.names = FALSE)
    trials <- unlist(trials, use.names = FALSE)
    tracks <- split(tracks, trials)
    ## report results
    list(iterations = i, tracks = tracks)
}
```

This is relatively fast, and can be manipulated to investigate properties, e.g.,

```
> n_trials <- 100000
> system.time(answer <- gamble2(n_trials, 6, 10, .5))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.172   0.000   2.172 
> tracks0 <- unlist(answer$tracks, use.names=FALSE)
> last <- cumsum(lengths(answer$tracks))
> table(tracks0[last]) / n_trials

      0      10 
0.39794 0.60206 
> hist(lengths(answer$tracks))
```

(`gamble1()`, since edited out, was trying to be too clever, using an environment to store the iterations; R has become much better at growing vectors and lists, so that kind of cleverness isn't necessary; this is also relevant to @Gregor 's advice to avoid growing vectors -- growing vectors by indexing past the end `x[i]` or `x[[i]]` is now reasonably performant in R).

Comment: Thank you for this different approach. It may seem complicated as for me now but I have some question : Why is it when i tried to run tracks0 it sends this error "Error in answer$tracks : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: I updated the function `gamble2()`, please try again.

Comment: I'm still studying how each line of your codes works. Soon I'll be able to understand this. Thank you for your ideas